# Why is sum not calculating the expected values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone explain why these lead to different results?

```
select distinct sku, product_title, sales_month
from ims_sales_data_history
where product_title = 'BERRY STRAWBERRY CV' 
and sales_month > 0
and department = 'Produce'
group by 1,2,3
```

Yields the following. Sum is 159 which is correct.

```
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 11
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 10
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 56
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 4
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 15
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 5
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 25
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 27
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 6
```

The query below has unique names which is what I want but incorrect sums.

```
SELECT product_title, SUM(sales_month)
FROM ims_sales_data_history
where department = 'Produce'
AND sales_month > 0
group by 1
```

Yields this: Sum of 194 (last row)

```
BERRY STRAWBERRY 16OZ CV    2584526
BERRY STRAWBERRY 32OZ OG    603817
BERRY STRAWBERRY 32OZ CV    465426
FC BERRY STRAWBERRY OG  74961
BERRY STRAWBERRY BULK BY LB CV  4371
BERRY STRAWBERRY 64OZ CV    780
BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 194
```

The desired output is unique names and the correct sum (159). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put you data on fiddle link please otherwise it will be tough to say what the actual problem

Comment: Remove the `distinct` from your first query and check the numbers again.

Comment: The first query uses DISTINCT and shows ony unique records (removes duplicates), while the second quesy sums all records. You are comparing apples to oranges, I vote to close this question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

They lead to different results because you have duplicates in your data.

Imagine that your data looks like this:

```
sku             product_title       sales_month
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 11
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 11
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 11
```

The first query will return:

```
0000000033565   BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 11
```

That appears to be what you want.

The second would return:

```
BERRY STRAWBERRY CV 33
```

I would advise you to fix your data source.  Having duplicates in the data is probably not correct.